# what is the overlay line on each bar in a bar chart?

Tags: charts, graph-visualization

I'm trying to learn myself with data visualization and when I'm going through the bar chart I'm stuck with the following thing.

In  the graph there is a vertical black line on each bar in the bar char. What exactly signifies that overlay-ed black line. Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like vertical [error bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_bar).

> Error bars are a graphical representation of the variability of data
>   and are used on graphs to indicate the error, or uncertainty in a
>   reported measurement.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same questions and did some researy with a summary below. Please share your thoughts if any misunderstanding.

The error bars shows the confidence interval Or Standard Deviation.

1. CI- a range of values that you can be x% certain contains the true mean of the population.
   [useful link](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/statistics/stat_more_about_confidence_interval.htm)
2. SD- require to be defined in the code.
   i.e.ax = sns.barplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, ci="sd")
   [useful link](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)